# git bisect for several git repos

Tags: python, git, unit-testing, integration-testing, git-bisect

[git-bisect](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) is a nice tool. But your software gets build from several repositories:

- core
- plugins
- customer-settings

Is there a way to use git-bisect if you know:

Test was good with

- core version123
- plugin1 version234
- plugin2 version567
- customer-settings version333

and fails with

- core version127
- plugin1 version237
- plugin2 version570
- customer-settings version338

Our code is written with Python, but that should not matter much for this topic.

Comment: Are your projects linked together in a parent repos, declared in it [as submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Comment: No we don't use submodules. And AFAIK we won't in the future. I can't change this at the moment.

Comment: Then I would presume git-bisect won't operate as you want on multiple projects.